# I'm getting a "Command ProcessProductPackagingDER failed with a nonzero exit code" and can't find any clues to what's causing it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

error build: Command ProcessProductPackagingDER failed with a nonzero exit code.
I get this error when I'm trying to build my project on XCode.

I've tried restarting Xcode, didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Same boat. Did you ever find the solution? When I click on the error, it says unable to reserialize input.

Answer (score 7):

Ran into the same error, and found that a single blank/empty line in the Entitlements file was the root cause. Removed the empty line and the build worked again.

Comment: I had an empty line in my entitlements file. I removed it, but the error persists. Did you perform any other steps after deleting the line?

Comment: A clean followed by a build.